# get selected item in a list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I have used a list view in view flipper, I want that when user selected a list item then it should be stay selected when user select other list item or come back to that "Listview" activity.how is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, docList, R.layout.your_layout,
            new String[] { "UserName", "Status"}, new int[] {
                    R.id.username, R.id.status});
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            registerForContextMenu(listView);
            listView.showContextMenu();

            tv = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.username);
            getListName = tv.getText().toString();               

            tv1 = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.status);
            getFriendUserId = tv1.getText().toString();  
        }
    });
```

Comment: i don't want this, i want that when i select an iten from list then it open data for that item,now when i come back to that list then the  item which was selected previously must be pre selected in that list.

Comment: why are you registering the ListView for context menu inside on item click, seriously that snippet is way too much wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                    View arg1, int position, long arg3)
        {
            String selectedItem = list.getSelectedItem().toString();    
        });
```

Here the selectedItem  contains the what you have selected in the list.